# Animate a percentage positioned DIV in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, html, percentage

I decided to improve my JavaScript skills by practicing with some often used modules.

I am creating a fixed feedback button that comes up when you press it and goes down when you press again. Everything works, but I want it to be animated.

I used this code to get it done

```
function rollUp(item){
       if(item.className == "on") {
          item.className="off";
          document.getElementById("container").style.top = "97%";
       } else {
          item.className="on";
          document.getElementById("container").style.top = "78.5%";
       }
    }
```

Now I just don't get those percentages animated, I found many descriptions about animating divs by px, but I don't get this working.

So the div has to be moved from top position 97% to 78.5%

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? If yea, please try this:

```
function rollUp(item){
   if(item.className == "on") {
      item.className="off";
      $("#container").animate({top: "97%"});
   } else {
      item.className="on";
      $("#container").animate({top: "78.5%"});
   }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm using plain JavaScript.

Comment: I can, but I was planning to learn plain JavaScript before using libraries to make my code cleaner. So if you have a advice on plain JavaScript that would be great!

Comment: Okay, it needs some more time from my side, since you needed an animation effect.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like a timeout which will change the position in small steps which actually is "animation", here

```
function rollUp(){
var ph=document.getElementById("container").style.top.toString();
ph.replace("px","");
var phi=parseInt(ph);
if(phi<800){
       if(item.className == "on") {
          item.className="off";
          document.getElementById("container").style.top = (phi+10).toString()+"px";
       } else {
          item.className="on";
          document.getElementById("container").style.top = "600px";
       }
Window.setTimeout(roolUp(), 300);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code? I will edit it and hopefully make it work, Thank you.